# A continuous function that is uniformly continuous on two sets, but not uniformly continuous on the union of these two sets?

Tags: real-analysis

This homework problem has just cost me 3 hours... But I still have no clue what it can be...

Let $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Find a continuous function $f:A\cup B \to \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and on $B$, but $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $A\cup B$.

Comment: The question is wrong if $A,B$ are compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: There is no restriction on what $A$ and $B$ could be as long as they are subsets of the reals.

Comment: The wording "Let $A,B\subseteq\mathbb R$" seems to imply that we're supposed to do this for arbitrarily given sets $A$ and $B$. I'm sure that wasn't intended; we get to pick the sets as well as the function. Badly worded problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\cos x^2, A=f^{-1}(1),B=f^{-1}(-1)$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: take $A=\mathbb N$ and $B=\{n+\frac{1}{n}\left|\right.n\in\mathbb N,n\geq 2\}$.

Comment: $f$ is meant to be continuous on $A \cup B$.

Comment: Oh, right; I edited the hint.

Comment: @detnvvp Why $A \cup B$ is not discrete?

Comment: @GA316 But, it is discrete.

Comment: @detnvvp so $f$ will be uniform in $A \cup B$ also no, since any function is uniformly continuous on discrete set?

Comment: @GA316 Any function defined on a discrete set is continuous, but not necessarily uniformly continuous.

Comment: @detnvvp ya. ya. now I understand. very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : union of two discrete sets need not be discrete